# How do I force OpenGL to clear an object for buffer processing with a QOpenGLWidget?

Tags: qt, opengl, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I developed a GUI tool (using PyQt5) that integrates OpenGL graphics (using [ModernGL](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL)) with a neural network to explore how neural networks fail when presented with certain object poses. The full source code is available [here](https://github.com/airalcorn2/strike-with-a-pose). For the "detector" and "mapper" modes, when the user queries the neural network by pressing a key, the neural network predictions are rendered on top of the object, e.g.:

[image: No class activation map.]
[image: With class activation map.]

Importantly, I tried to set it up such that if the user queries the neural network a second time without altering anything, the tool ***first clears the old prediction*** before generating a new prediction to render. Here's that bit of code:

```python
def get_prediction(self):

    self.model.clear()
    # self.scene.CTX.finish()

    buffer = QtCore.QBuffer()
    buffer.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadWrite)
    qimage = self.grabFramebuffer()
    qimage.save(buffer, "PNG")

    strio = io.BytesIO()
    strio.write(buffer.data())
    buffer.close()
    strio.seek(0)
    pil_im = Image.open(strio)
    pil_im = pil_im.resize(self.scene.WINDOW_SIZE)

    self.model.predict(pil_im)
```

`model.clear()` releases the prediction's texture, vertex array, and vertex buffer. This *seems* to work in that if I press the query key multiple times, the rendered image remains the same (i.e., the neural network is only using the scene to generate the heat map, not the scene *with* the heat map). If I comment out the `model.clear()` line, I get things like the following sequence:

[image]
[image]

where the heat map changes on each query because the neural network is using the scene ***with*** the heat map as input. However, the tool also has a "live" mode where `get_prediction` is called each time `paintGL` is called, and even with the `model.clear()` line uncommented, the renderer exhibits the second behavior where the heat map is constantly changing rather than remaining static. As you can see in the above code, one thing I attempted was calling `finish` on the context following the call to `model.clear()`, which is supposed to "[Wait for all drawing commands to finish,](https://moderngl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/context.html#moderngl.Context.finish)" (like [`glFinish`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glFinish.xhtml)), but that didn't work. I also tried setting the `QSurfaceFormat` swap behavior with:

```python
fmt.setSwapBehavior(QSurfaceFormat.SingleBuffer)
```

but that also didn't work. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that it seemed to be working when not in live mode was a red herring that sent me down the wrong path. The fix was the obvious one of making sure I was properly clearing and rendering things in the right order. The commit can be found [here](https://github.com/airalcorn2/strike-with-a-pose/commit/eed5a779d3d3682c957f6e0e701a6355c4f98775).